# ldap_search() by GUID in AD with Php

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, guid

I am beginner (and sorry for my english). I develop a php API to interact with LDAP directories.
I would search users by their objectGUID in my AD. I can't search for more than 2 characters...

I tried to apply this method found on phpdoc of ldap_search() :

`ldap_search($ds,"dc=blahblah,dc=com", "(objectGUID=\\AE\\C3\\23\\35\\F7)");`

but i don't how to replace AE, C3, ...

With `$id = "4a3ef66a-ff9f-4e84-ad8d-dd3378e8df19";`

---

**I tried to start with a simple problem :**

`$filters = "(objectGUID=*\\4a*)";  //(objectGUID=*\4a*)`

-> It works ! An user is found.

---

**I tried with more :**

`$filters = "(objectGUID=*\\4a3e*)";  //(objectGUID=*\4a3e*)`

-> ldap_search($filters, [...]) then ldap_get_entries() : count=0

---

**I tried :**

`$filters = "(objectGUID=*\\4a\\3e*)";  //(objectGUID=*\4a\3e*)`

-> ldap_search($filters, [...]) then ldap_get_entries() : count=0

---

**I tried :**

`$filters = "(objectGUID=*\\4a-3e*)";  //(objectGUID=*\4a-3e*)`

-> ldap_search($filters, [...]) then ldap_get_entries() : count=0

---

**I tried :**

`$filters = "(objectGUID=*\\4a*3e*)";  //(objectGUID=*\4a*3e*)`

-> ldap_search($filters, [...]) then ldap_get_entries() : count=0

---

#### Do you know a good way to search an user in AD by objectGUID with Php ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You filter needs to be something like

```
(objectGUID=\90\39\5F\19\1A\B5\1B\4A\9E\96\86\C6\6C\B1\8D\11)
```

objectGUID are stored in Microsoft Active Directory as a "relicaLink" which appears to be like an octetString. I do not think substring searches will work.

More info at:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=ObjectGUID